# Export of a realm from a running keycloak docker container fails

Tags: docker, keycloak

I am running keycloak v8.0.0 using docker compose file. I am persisting the data into a MySQL database which I am running locally.

```
  version: '3'
  services:
   keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:8.0.0
    ports:
      - "9999:8080"
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: <ADMIN_PASSWORD>
      DB_VENDOR: mysql
      DB_ADDR: <HOST>
      DB_PORT: <PORT>
      DB_USER: <USER>
      DB_PASSWORD: <PASSWORD>
      JDBC_PARAMS: "useSSL=false"
    volumes:
      - "./realms:/tmp"
```

I tried exporting a realm from the running docker container by using following command.

```
docker exec -it kc /opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh \
-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100 -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export \
-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile \
-Dkeycloak.migration.realmName=my_realm\
-Dkeycloak.migration.usersExportStrategy=REALM_FILE \
-Dkeycloak.migration.file=/tmp/my_realm-realm.json
```

Below is the stack trace of the error i am getting when I run the above command. When I am running the above command keycloak is not able to connect to database server i.e. MySQL in this case. How to specify database connection configuration in this scenario?

```
16:30:04,000 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."keycloak-server.war".undertow-deployment: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."keycloak-server.war".undertow-deployment: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication()
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:81)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: RESTEASY003325: Failed to construct public org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication()
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:164)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2784)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:364)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:277)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:89)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:119)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:585)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:556)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.26.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:598)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@18.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@8.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:372)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@8.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lazyInit(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:65)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@8.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lambda$waitForLock$2(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:96)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@8.0.0//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:682)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@8.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.waitForLock(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:94)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:178)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@8.0.0//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:171)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.init(KeycloakApplication.java:162)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@8.0.0//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:143)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.9.0.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:159)
        at org.jboss.as.connector@18.0.0.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@8.0.0//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:366)
        ... 45 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:690)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:440)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1328)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:499)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:632)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:604)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 97 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 91 milliseconds ago.
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:201)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:4912)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1663)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1224)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2190)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2221)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2016)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:386)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.17.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:169)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:98)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:216)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:395)
        at com.mysql.jdbc@5.1.46//com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:186)
        ... 73 more
```

Answer (score 4):

The first solution did not work for me, so I had to investigate further. In my case, the reason was, that the DB_PORT environment variable was not added to the connection string, so keycloak tried to connect to the postgres DB under the dafault port 5432, as seen in this log:

```
11:29:10,185 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) FINE: Connecting with URL: jdbc:postgresql://156149bb-0045-4086-b11a-1b55458b2a5f.blrv234f085n1l00bhrg.private.databases.appdomain.cloud/ibmclouddb?connectTimeout=30&ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory&loggerLevel=DEBUG
[...]
11:29:10,194 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) FINE: Trying to establish a protocol version 3 connection to 156149bb-0045-4086-b11a-1b55458b2a5f.blrv234f085n1l00bhrg.private.databases.appdomain.cloud:5432
```

So I added the Port to the DB_ADDR variable and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error today,and found is the JDBC_PARAMS format error;

so you can exec in the container,

```
docker exec -it kc bash
```

and modify the JDBC_PARAMS

```
# Append '?' in the beggining of the string if JDBC_PARAMS value isn't empty
export JDBC_PARAMS=$(echo ${JDBC_PARAMS} | sed '/^$/! s/^/?/')
```

Or redefine JDBC_PARAMS env

```
export JDBC_PARAMS='?connectTimeout=30&useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8'
```

the key is prefix `?` char

then exec

```
/opt/jboss/keycloak/bin/standalone.sh \
-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=100 -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export \
-Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile \
-Dkeycloak.migration.realmName=my_realm\
-Dkeycloak.migration.usersExportStrategy=REALM_FILE \
-Dkeycloak.migration.file=/tmp/my_realm-realm.json
```

everything is OK!